# (proof clarification) - ( E, $\mathscr{F}_G$) is a matroid

Tags: graph-theory, proof-explanation, trees, matroids

I'm having trouble understanding why we make the assumption in the highlighted part of the proof, any help would be appreciate, thanks.

> **Proposition.** $\forall G = (V,E)$ undirected graph, the pair $(E, \mathscr {F}_G)$ is a matroid.
> $$\mathscr {F}_G = \{A \subseteq E: (V,A)\space \text{is a forest}\}$$
> Proof uses this lemma
>
> > **Lemma.** Every forest with $n$ nodes and $k$ trees has $n-k$ edges.

**Proof.** Consider $A,B\in \mathscr {F}_G$, $|B| = |A| +1 $ and $|V| = n$, than $(V,A)$ and $(V,B)$ has the same number of nodes $n$ but $(V,A)$ has an edge less and so one more tree.

> $\exists u,v \in V $ in the same  tree in $(V,B)$ but different tree in $(V,A)$, so exist a  path $C = ( u=b_0,b_1, ...,b_n=v)$ connecting $u\to v$ in $B$. Must exist an edge $(b_i,b_{i+1}) \notin A$ and in two different trees in $A$.

So $$A\cup\{(b_1, b_{i+1})\}$$
does not form cycles and $(V, A\cup\{(b_1, b_{i+1})\})$ is a forest. $\blacksquare$

Why can't we just suppose the existence of $b_i,b_{i+1}$ call them $u,v$ without mentioning $C$, is less precise or is it wrong? To me it doesn't seem to be a problem but if the proof is written as it is surely there must be a reason.

Comment: what do you mean by "suppose the existance of $b_i$"?

Comment: @Phicar why do we have to say that $\exists u,v$ and they are connected etc... and why  not say, $\exists (b_i, b_{i+1})$ edge in $B$ and not edge in $A$, to me seems the same but the second statement is more straight forward to me

Comment: Such $u$ and $v$ are connected by a path, but not necessarily by a single edge. You only know that somewhere in the path there must be an edge in $B$ but not in $A$